# Google App Engine problem. URL grouping not working

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud, app.yaml

My app was working fine in php55 using the below app.yaml settings to grouped URLs. E.G. /api/manage, /api/edit, api/user/add should all be forwarded to  /api/api.php  but stopped working when upgraded to php72.

Fine below the app.yaml conifig for both php55 and php72 for your help.

Configuration for php55

```
service: default
runtime: php55

    handlers:
    
      - url: /api((/$)|(/[^/]+(/$)?)*)
        script: /api/api.php
        secure: always
```

Configuration for php72

```
service: default
runtime: php72

handlers:

  - url: /api/(.*?)/(.*)
    script: /api/api.php
    secure: always
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd generation runtimes (including PHP 7+) you no longer use the `script` element to route traffic ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/php-differences)).  You have to use a language idiomatic web/routing framework (e.g. Flask in Python, a [front controller](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime#app_startup) for PHP).